# InputBinding and WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, commandbinding, inputbinding

I have a very simple application where I'm trying to bind keyboard shortcuts to a WPF command that is bound to a menu item. The application itself consists of just a `Menu` and a `WebBrowser` control.

When I'm within the `WebBrowser`, the keyboard shortcuts are not routed up to the WPF Menu. For example, typing 'Ctrl+O' when focused in the web browser shows the IE open page. Additionally, in this application, unless I have the Menu focused (by typing in Alt) the input bindings don't fire. For example, I can't focus on the WPF window by clicking on the title bar and then type the shortcuts. The full code is replicated below:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestInputBindingsOnMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" x:Name="_mainMenu" Grid.Row="0" />
        <WebBrowser Source="http://google.com" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TestInputBindingsOnMenu
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            MenuItem fileMenu = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem fileNew = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem fileOpen = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem fileExit = new MenuItem();

            fileMenu.Header = "File";
            fileNew.Header = "New";
            fileOpen.Header = "Open";
            fileExit.Header = "Exit";

            fileMenu.Items.Add(fileNew);
            fileMenu.Items.Add(fileOpen);
            fileMenu.Items.Add(fileExit);

            _mainMenu.Items.Add(fileMenu);

            var fileNewCommand = CreateCommand("New");
            var fileOpenCommand = CreateCommand("Open");
            var fileExitCommand = CreateCommand("Exit");

            _mainMenu.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(fileNewCommand, ExecuteNew));
            _mainMenu.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(fileOpenCommand, ExecuteOpen));
            _mainMenu.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(fileExitCommand, ExecuteExit));

            fileNew.Command = fileNewCommand;
            fileOpen.Command = fileOpenCommand;
            fileExit.Command = fileExitCommand;

            _mainMenu.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(fileNewCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control)));
            _mainMenu.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(fileOpenCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.O, ModifierKeys.Control)));
            _mainMenu.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(fileExitCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)));
        }

        private void ExecuteNew(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New!!");
        }

        private void ExecuteOpen(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Open!!");
        }

        private void ExecuteExit(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exit!!");
        }

        private static RoutedCommand CreateCommand(string label)
        {
            return new RoutedCommand(label, typeof(MainWindow));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy Solution**

Add the input bindings to the WebBrowser control as well as the main menu:

```
Browser.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ApplicationCommands.Open, 
new KeyGesture(Key.O, ModifierKeys.Control)));
```

**Hard Solution**

What is happening here is that the `UIElement` is using the `KeyDown` event, while you want to use `PreviewKeyDown` event, or add a handler that also handles `Handled` routed events. Look up [Tunnelling and Bubbling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) if you don't know about this.

Since this is handled in the UIElement class, I would advise using a different pattern in this situation. [The MVVM Light framework](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) provides an `EventToCommand` behavior. If you can route the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the window to the right commands instead of using `KeyBinding` with the `InputBindings` collection of the `UIElement` you will have your solution.

You will need some custom code to check which key was pressed and to which command the routing should be.

Comment: This did mostly what I wanted, except if the focus is not on the browser or the menu. I tried adding the command binding to the MainWindow but that didn't help either. In the example above, for example (after adding the bindings to the browser control), if I type in one of the commands (which pops up a message box) and then click enter, I can no longer execute any more shortcuts until I click within the browser control again.

Comment: Try adding them to both the browser and the main window!

Comment: I did add them to the browser and mainwindow as well as the menu.